# flow chart drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

The code that i have made for the following flow chart creates paths (arrows) which are shorter than the others. besides i don't know how to put the word department on top other box. here is my code

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=white, node distance=2cm, text width=16em,  text centered, minimum height=4em, thick]



\tikzstyle{blks} = [rectangle, draw, fill=white, node distance=1.5cm, text width=6em,  text centered, minimum height=4em, dashed]


\tikzstyle{big} = [rectangle, draw, inner sep=0.5cm, thick]

\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex',thick]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\node [block](exe) {\textbf{Executive}};
\node [block, below=of exe] (mgm) {\textbf{Departmental managers}};
\node [blks, below=of mgm] (fin) {Finance};
\node [blks, right=of fin] (prod) {Production};
 \node [blks, left=of fin] (resch) {Research};

\node [block, below=of fin] (sub) {\textbf{Sub-ordinate}};

\node [big,fit=(fin) (prod)(resch)] (dept) {\textbf{Departments}};

\path [line] (exe)--(mgm);
\path [line] (mgm) -- (dept);
\path [line] (resch)--(fin);
\path [line] (fin)--(prod);
\path [line] (dept) -- (sub); 


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an attempt. An extra node called `A` is added to form a new fit with `fin, prod, resch`

Also please see [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/34618)

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=white,text width=16em,  text centered, minimum height=4em, thick]

\tikzstyle{blks} = [rectangle, draw, fill=white, text width=6em,  text centered, minimum height=4em, dashed]

\tikzstyle{big} = [rectangle, draw, inner sep=0.5cm]

\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex',thick]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\node [block](exe) {\textbf{Executive}};
\node [block, below=of exe] (mgm) {\textbf{Departmental managers}};
\node [blks, below=2cm of mgm] (fin) {Finance};
\node [blks, right=of fin] (prod) {Production};
\node [blks, left=of fin] (resch) {Research};

\node [block, below= 2cm of fin] (sub) {\textbf{Sub-ordinate}};
\node[above =0.2cm of  fin] (A) {\textbf{Department}};
\node [below = 0.3 of mgm, big,fit=(fin) (prod)(resch)(A), inner sep=0.5cm] (dept) {};

\path [line] (exe)--(mgm);
\path [line] (mgm) -- (dept);
\path [line] (resch)--(fin);
\path [line] (fin)--(prod);
\path [line] (dept) -- (sub); 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please note the shifted `(fin)` to get the same arrow lengths

Answer (score 2):

Jesse's answer is fine, I'll have some remarks and an alternative solution regarding the arrow length in this answer:

You set different node distances in `block` and `blks` which are ordered horizontally and vertically. You can have that in one setting for the whole picture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm and 1.5cm]
```

The arrow length are different because the nodes are placed at equal distances but the arrows connect to different things (distance: mgmt to fin, arrow: mgmt to dept). This can be solved by placing the (dept) node first with an invisible border.

```
\node [block](exe) {\textbf{Executive}};
\node [block, below=of exe] (mgm) {\textbf{Departmental managers}};

\node[block, draw=none, below=of mgm] (deptlabel)   {\textbf{Departments}};

% place fin node right next to the label, the "inner sep" will keep the distance
\node [blks, below=0cm of deptlabel] (fin) {Finance};
\node [blks, right=of fin] (prod) {Production};
\node [blks, left=of fin] (resch) {Research};
```

Then for the box draw a vertically close fitting node (`inner ysep = 0`) and shift the (fin) node a bit to maintain the margin.

```
\node [big,inner ysep=0cm,fit={
    (prod)(resch) 
    (deptlabel) ([yshift=-0.5cm]fin.south) }] (dept) {};
```

rest as usual.

This approach will keep the globally set distances and inner separation intact, with the exception of the single `yshift` that would need to be adjusted if the other stuff changes.

Here the result and a version with some changes that indicates how it works.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this nicely using the [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it) library for drawing boxes (documented [here](http://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpboxes.pdf)).

[image]

I've used the `image` operator to do the boxes within a box.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
input boxes;
beginfig(1);

% extra space around the contents of the boxes 
defaultdx := 5mm;
defaultdy := 3mm;

% use Helvetica
defaultfont := "phvr8r";

% first make a picture of the departments
picture dep;
dep = image(
    boxit.res("Research");
    boxit.fin("Finance");
    boxit.prod("Production");
    (3cm,0) = prod.c - fin.c = fin.c - res.c;
    drawboxed(res,fin,prod);
    drawarrow res.e -- fin.w;
    drawarrow fin.e -- prod.w;
    label("Departments",fin.n + 9 up);
);

% now define four more boxes...
boxit.exec("Executive");
boxit.mgmt("Management");
boxit.dept(dep);
boxit.sub("Sub-ordinate");

% ... arranged vertically, 
(0,8mm) = exec.s-mgmt.n = mgmt.s-dept.n = dept.s-sub.n;

% ... and draw them plus connecting arrows
drawboxed(exec,mgmt,dept,sub);
drawarrow exec.s -- mgmt.n;
drawarrow mgmt.s -- dept.n;
drawarrow dept.s -- sub.n;

endfig;
end.
```

According to the manual linked above the syntax of `boxit` is

```
boxit.⟨suffix⟩(⟨picture expression⟩)
```

so I was expecting to be able to write `boxit.sss(image(....));` but this produces errors with the bounding box macros in `boxes.mp` if the image contains other `boxit` instructions.  It is not clear to me why this is the case, but using a temporary picture variable as the `⟨picture expression⟩` works fine.